# SIGSEGV crash on iOS, caused by _Z4bootiPPc

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault, crittercism

I am trying to figure out this crash which was reported through crittercism for an app I am working on for iOS.

I've been searching for an answer, but without any luck.

The name of the crash is **SIGSEGV** and it is caused by **_Z4bootiPPc**.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib      0x3a521564 _cache_getImp + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib      0x3a5231d7 class_respondsToSelector + 31
2   CoreFoundation       0x328a8605 objectIsKindOfClass + 37
3   CoreFoundation       0x328a835d __handleUncaughtException + 69
4   libobjc.A.dylib      0x3a526a65 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 129
5   libc++abi.dylib      0x39f7307b _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib      0x39f73114 _ZSt9terminatev + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib      0x39f74599 __cxa_current_exception_type + 1
8   libobjc.A.dylib      0x3a5269d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 13
9   CoreFoundation       0x327eef21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 457
10  CoreFoundation       0x327eed49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
11  GraphicsServices     0x363a12eb GSEventRunModal + 75
12  UIKit                0x34704301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
13  ApplicationProcess   0x00bd733b boot (main.mm:8)
14  ApplicationProcess   0x00bddee9 main (MainCpp.cpp:13)
```

This is the register data from the crashed thread:

```
r0: 0x40000000  r1: 0x3834311f  r2: 0x0 r3: 0x1
r4: 0x3834311f  r5: 0x26d79a20  r6: 0x0 r7: 0x2fd0b90c
r8: 0x40000000  r9: 0xe0d0c47   r10: 0x0    r11: 0x0
sp: 0x2fd0b8f4  lr: 0x3a521f89  pc: 0x3a521564  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Does anyone have a clue of what is causing the crash, other than it is SIGSEGV?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about posting some more information. Including, but not limited to, the code in which you THINK is causing the problem.

Comment: The project is huge, and the crash has been there since crittercism was included, so I wouldn't have a clue :/

Comment: If you can debug this, enable exception breakpoints. Otherwise get the last exception backtrace and the actual exception reason text of the crash.

Comment: Symbolication of your app will greatly facilitate your ability to perform Root Cause Analysis.